# Firebase and recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm new in firebase and android studio and I have a problem

I want to store the data of this database in an array and next use the array to make a recycler view

[image]

Then in the main activity I wrote this:

[image]

And if I run the app only this is shown:

[image]

But if I do the same but instead of firebase i use a String[] with the data i want to show it works but i don't know why with firebase i can't.

if I change the references by this:

```
reference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.POKEMONS_REFERENCES);
      reference.child(FirebaseReferences.APP_REFERENCES).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

when I run the app, it automatically closes and i don't know what to do.

Could you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Here is the logCat
https://github.com/adcasna/SearchViewPrueba2/wiki

Comment: Show your logcat.

Comment: Ater the for loop try calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you should add your code in the question instead of adding a picture..

Comment: I tried calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but still not working

Comment: Here is the logcat

https://github.com/adcasna/SearchViewPrueba2/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisrts of all, please note that the Firebase documentation recommends against using arrays. Using an array is an anti-pattern when it comes to Firebase. One of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write. If you still want to use this kind of structure, for getting those names and store them in an  `ArrayList`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference appRef = rootRef.child("pokemons").child("app");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String c_name = ds.child("c_name").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(c_name);
            Log.d("TAG", c_name);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
appRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```